# Obtaining PayPalEnvironmentProduction string

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I have this in my `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        PayPalMobile .initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments(
            [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "How to get this one?",
             PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "I know how to get this"])
        return true
    }
```

So, to get client id for a sandbox environment, I create an app in PayPal Dashboard section and I can see Client ID there for sandbox environment. But how to obtain another required parameter?

Comment: You have to upgrade your paypal account to obtain your client id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this link to know about the procedure to upgrade your Paypal account :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/#upgrade-your-paypal-account-as-necessary

> API Credentials
>
> The sandbox or live account client ID and secret used to make API
>   calls. You can use your sandbox credentials to begin testing. To use
>   your live credentials, you might need to upgrade your PayPal account.
>   Keep your app credentials private to protect you and your customers.

The live credentials are what you need.

Instructions to follow are there to use a production account:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-vzero/testing-go-live/ruby/

Comment: Hey, thanks for a quick response! Actually, I am able to obtain client ID for live credentials ...  Let me get this clear... I have to get client ID from *Live* tab, right ? I thought I don't need that for Sandbox testing :|

Comment: Also I have Personal type of an account.

Comment: For testing you don't need to provide live credential ! I will check my code.

Comment: Well I guess I don't need live credentials, but I have to provide some parameter to that method (I guess).

Comment: I think that you can put a random string for this parameter. I don't have access to my code for now but you can try to copy past your sandbox ID as the environment ID. It will works

Comment: I tried that...But I get error which says that connection is lost on both simulator and device... I don't know why that error happens though, but I thought it is because of a missing credential.

Comment: When do you get this error ? When you try to connect with your paypal account or when you try to simulate a payment ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113035/discussion-between-anthony-roani-and-whirlwind).